# What is the correct pH value of weak and strong alkalis?

Tags: physical-chemistry, acid-base, ph

In the book titled fundamental chemistry for Cambridge O level, it states at page 149,

> Ammonia solution with a pH of 11.1 is a weak alkali and that's why it shows much lower conductivity of 0.50 US/cm.

However at p. 147 it's written that

> a solution with a pH of 10 is a strong alkali.

So either the correlation of pH with conductivity is incorrect  or the statement that ammonia solution with a pH of 11.1 is a weak Alkali is wrong.   What are the pH values for a weak and strong Alkali?

Is there anything wrong with the two diametrically opposite sentences/ statements given in the book?

Comment: Proper word is **base** and it's strength has nothing to do with pH!

Answer (score 6):

There might be confusion as below:

**strong/weak "Alkali"(1)** - or rather an alkaline solution, which is related to the $\mathrm{pH}$ value. The conductivity and the strength increases with $\ce{pH}$, but conductivity can be obviously affected by presence of salts.
There is not a strict threshold between strong or weak alkaline $\ce{pH}$. It is often considered relatively and/or it depends on context. As a guide the threshold can be between 10-12, context dependent.

**strong/weak "Alkali"(2)** - or rather a base ( as an opposite to an acid ), which is related to the base dissociation constant. IF a base has too low dissociation constant, so there is significant fraction of not dissociated base ( like ammonia ), the base is considered a weak base. There is ongoing equilibrium $\ce{ BOH <=> B+ + OH-}$, resp. $\ce{ B + H2O <=> BH+ + OH-}$

---

E.g. 
$\ce{NaOH}$ solution with $\mathrm{pH} = 10$ is weak "alkali"(1), but strong "alkali"(2).

$\ce{NH3}$ solution with $\mathrm{pH} = 11$ is stronger "alkali"(1) then above, but weak "alkali"(2).

Note: For historical reasons, "**alkali**" is reserved to hydroxides of alkalic metals, so it should not be used for ammonia. As the general term, a base is preferred, with alkalic/alkaline ( along with basic ) as adjective being accepted.

Answer (score 3):

In the 19th century, ammonia solutions were called "volatile alkali" by druggists and keepers of hardware shops. And sometimes the word "volatile" was omitted by subsidiary people. This information was given to me a long time ago by my father who was a druggist in a hardware shop in the first half of the 20th century (I am an old man, born 1937). I am surprised to see that this word "alkali" is still used for ammonia solutions in a serious document... It should not.

Comment: I recently worked at a company with people who had been with the company 50 years(!), and when it started, the chemist was already old. The names toluol and xylol kept being used. BTW, 83 isn't old; you are just up to bismuth. You have another 35 to go.

Comment: I wouldn't tell my age (or other data) on the net without good reason. Also this is more of a comment on archaic wording then full answer.